# Angular render template and store it to local

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I have a template (partial) that I use in few parts of my app problem is rendering this template takes a bit 1-3 seconds. I optimized the rendering process as much as I could but it's still a bit slow.

My template:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index">
  <div ng-repeat="col in row track by $index">
    <div class="column" ng-click="checkColumn($parent.$index, $index, col)">
      <img ng-src="..." ng-if="col.checked" />
      <img ng-src="..." ng-if="col.reserved" />
      <img ng-src="..." ng-if="col.used" />
      <img ng-src="..." ng-if="col.locked" />

      <img ng-src="..." ng-if="col.private" />
      <img ng-src="..." ng-if="col.disabled" />
      <img ng-src="..." ng-if="col.large" />
      <img ng-src="..." ng-if="col.small" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On average there are 15 `rows` and each `row` usually has avg. 17 `cols`. So usually about 255 `<div class="column">` get created.

My idea was to when the application is loading before visiting the screen where this is show to get `rows` from the API than pass them to this template have it render.

Than save `rows` and `rendered template` to local storage. Than in rest of my controllers where I need this I can just restore rows from local storage and inject template from local storage.

Just not sure exactly how I would go about this on AngularJS side.

Comment: A quick question: can a `.column` have more than one `img` displayed at once? If not, you could aggregate all the `ngIfs` into one `img`.

Comment: @CosminAbabei I always has only one image however the src for each image is different.

Comment: Hi, are you sure in using `ng-if`? Mostly, it's used when you need to re-init controller bind to directive etc. I suggest try using `ng-show` instead. This will speed up your second rendering (coz it will be not rendering but just showing hidden elements what is much faster)

Comment: @Appeiron The difference between ng-show and ng-if seems marginal.Very small I initially get ng-show the ng-if was a tiny tiny bit faster.

Comment: @SterlingDuchess I'm sure you can aggregate all the `ngIfs` inside `ngSrc` since it works with Angular expressions. This would give you a performance boost as you'll trim down the number on watchers.

Comment: @Cosmin Ababei yup, like `ng-src="col.image"`

`constructor() {
    this.setImagesForCols(rows);
}

setImagesForCols (rows) {
    setTimeout(() => {
         // for every col assign .image property based on your constant
    }, 0)
}
`

Comment: @Sterling Duchess I highly recommend using `setTimeout` to prevent any freezes if you are having real bunch of data.

Comment: @CosminAbabei Ok there was a boost but still not enough. What about my question abotu rendering it in the background and saving the template and rows into localStorage ?

Comment: @Appeiron It's somewhat smooth rendering just still slow I was thinking of saving it to locaStorage once rendered so next time I can just pull it from there and not have to rerender it again.

Comment: Bad idea. What if data was changed? You will never know it, when you are getting stored elements from LS, unless you have any header or prop in request telling ya it still the same. You can not re-use rendered element for Angular just in case it will be anyway re-calculated (coz Angular is recompiling your template if you are reloading). If you want real cache but only for live time of app, you can try replacing your template right in `$templateCache`

Comment: @Appeiron The data wont change. Rows remains the same when user logs in I pull it from DB and keep it until they are logged out then erase it. This is an internal app.

I would like to fetch rows from API render the template so ng-repeat does it's thing. Than I would save both rows and template to localstorage. Than once in my view I would do $scope.rows = localstorage.get('rows');  $scope.template = localstorage.get('template');

Than in my template I would just do {{ template }} if the hash of rows is the same that should not trigger a redraw correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general - you are free to store templates as static HTML in LS, and don't worry about any Angular `ng-click` etc. As all your data will be treated as static HTML, any Angular attributes will be compiled and working.

I've made example how to do this via template, hope it will be answer for you.

**HTML:**

`<div ng-app="app" id="app">
   <cached-directive></cached-directive>
</div>`

**JS:**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
var data = [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}];

var cachedDirective = function ($compile) {
 var directiveCtrl = function () {
   this.somevar = Date.now();
  }
  
  directiveCtrl.prototype.sayHi = function () {
   alert(1);
  }
 
  var originTemplate_ = '<b>{{ctrl.somevar}} TEST </b><button ng-click="ctrl.sayHi()">HELLO</button>';
  
  return {
  template: localStorage.template || originTemplate_,
    controller: directiveCtrl,
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
     setTimeout(function () {  
        localStorage.template = el.html();
     })
    }
  };
}

app.directive('cachedDirective', cachedDirective);
```

Try it at fiddle, I've provided in comments.

**P.S.** Don't forget to update your template in LS each time, something changed.